# Recommendation for a library to calculate the local volatility surface?

Tags: implied-volatility, local-volatility

I'd like a library to calculate the options local volatility surface, i.e. the options implied volatility surface  for a collection of strikes and their bid/ask prices.

Here are the libraries I've looked at:

- [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml) (Quote: "from memory, the function qlBlackVol will interpolate vols making sure that the surface is arbitrage free" (see [forum post](http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=34384)).
- [NAG](http://www.nag.co.uk/) (see "[Using the NAG Toolbox for MATLAB in Mathematical ﬁnance](http://www.nag.co.uk/about/student_awards/nicoletta_gabrielli_presentation.pdf)").
- [Intermark Tookits](http://www.intermarkit.com/toolkit/module_options.asp).
- [Modelling the implied volatility surface: an empirical study for FTSE options](http://www.amadeo.name/modelling.html) (contains source code).
- [Consistent Pricing of FX Options](http://www.fabiomercurio.it/consistentfxsmile.pdf) (doesn't calculate a surface, but interesting nevertheless).
- [Strata from OpenGamma](https://strata.opengamma.io/) (apparently, the source contains Java calls to calculate the local volatility surface).

Do you know of any other libraries?

Comment: p.s. Here are the search terms I used: "implied volatility surface", "local volatility surface", "black volatility surface" surface".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own library - not easy, but doable.

Comment: Can you please share some details on the procedure you followed? Is your calibration fully non parametric?

Answer (score 3):

The OpenGamma Analytics Library definitely does have a Local Volatility model available. In addition, in our [Quantitative Papers](https://strata.opengamma.io/quant_research/) page there's a link to the full mathematics and basis for our Local Volatility implementation.

I'd be interested to know why you decided to write your own rather than using one of the above.

Comment: I get an `Access Denied` error when i try and visit your link.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the closed form solution of [local volatility function](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2906522), a paper I just finished. This can help you visualize what it looks like.